# To use "not" or "don't" in a noun clause?

Tags: grammar

As in this sentence: "[We ask that you not take anything you read here as final.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#disclaimer)", why "not" is used instead of "don't"?

Comment: It has to do with the subjunctive mood.  In subjunctive clauses, negation occurs before the verb: i.e. *I ask that he not bring it*, but almost never *I ask that he do not bring it.*

Comment: The verb "ask" can be a **mandative verb**. That means that it ("ask") can take a **mandative clause** as its complement. One type of mandative clause is the subjunctive clause, which uses a plain form of the verb--in your example, the verb *"take"* is a plain form (it is not tensed).

Comment: Why don't you folks answer instead of commenting?

Comment: @F.E. Do you mean I should write "_I ask that he bring it_" instead of "_I ask that he brings it_". You should have put them as answers instead.

Comment: I brought up the topic of **mandative** so that you could search around for more info related to your question--info gotten on grammar sites and forums can often be unreliable, imo. (For me to write a post, it would take up an hour or two of my time, or more. For me to write a comment, like I did earlier--a few minutes.)

Comment: If the question is still unanswered in the morning, I will write an answer up. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of the [mandative subjunctive](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Mandative-Subjunctive.htm), which is a clause following a mandative word (expressing a *demand*, *requirement*, *request*, *recommendation*, *insistence* or *suggestion*) and usually, but not always, begins with 'that' and contains a *bare infinitive.*

The bare infinitive can be hard to spot. With inflected verbs such as *be*, it's easy, as the inflected forms are 'am, are, is', whereas the bare form is 'be'.

> I suggest that you *be* careful.

The important word is the mandative word.

> We *demand* that he *return* the item immediately.
>   He *insists* that Jones *go* first.

Your example (the mandative word is *request* or *ask*):

> We *ask* that you not *take* anything you read here as final.

is simply a negative mandate. The bare infinitive is *take*. The negative is *not take*.

If it were not the subjunctive, do not/don't would be fine. It might read:

> Please don't take anything you read here as final. (not a mandate)

Examples of other negative mandative subjunctives:

> - We ask that you *not bring* pets into the area.
> - The Park Service requests that you *not hike* this trail in the event of storms.
> - We request that you *not send* private information to us by email...
> - We ask that you *not eat or drink* for 12 hours prior to surgery...

Comment: Not too common in the UK:
"Divergent regional trends in the use of the subjunctive have been noted by a number of modern English grammarians. Use of the mandative subjunctive, i.e. after expressions of demand, recommendation, intention, etc., seems to have varied considerably. AmE is strongly inclined to use the mandative subjunctive, as in 'I recommend that he talk to a [doctor]', while BrE prefers the periphrastic construction with the modal auxiliary should, as in 'I recommend that he should talk to a [doctor]'."

(Peter Collins and Pam Peters, "Australian English: Morphology and Syntax."

Comment: +1 For confirmation, consider the affirmative version: *We ask that you take anything you read here as final*. If *do* were inserted, it would change the meaning, adding significant emphasis or insistance.